# Что такое облачный IP адрес?

Tags: linux, ip, хостинг, backend, vps

Что такое облачный IP адрес? Чем он отличается от IPv4?

Comment: Где вы нашли такой термин?

Answer (score 1):

Часто под термином "Облачный IP" подразумевается ситуация, когда сервер доступен по этому адресу только внутри самого облака (точнее даже внутри какого-то участка облака), а для получения данных от него из интернета требуется иметь в этом же облаке еще один отдельный сервер с внешним IP адресом, либо же прибегать к какой-либо CDN или еще какому-либо посреднику. В этом плане термин "Облачный IP" скорее относится к терминам группы "серый IP" и "белый IP".

Comment: В качестве анг. синонима может использоваться термин "Private IP" (в противоположность "Public IP").